# Delphi Assembly Function Returning a Long String

Tags: string, delphi, function, assembly, basm

I am trying to learn inline assembly programming in Delphi, and to this end I have found [this article](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3766.asp) highly helpful.

Now I wish to write an assembly function returning a long string, specifically an `AnsiString` (for simplicity). I have written

```
function myfunc: AnsiString;
asm
  // eax = @result
  mov edx, 3
  mov ecx, 1252
  call System.@LStrSetLength
  mov [eax + 0], ord('A')
  mov [eax + 1], ord('B')
  mov [eax + 2], ord('C')
end;
```

Explanation:

A function returning a string has an invisible `var result: AnsiString` (in this case) parameter, so, at the beginning of the function, `eax` should hold the address of the resulting string. I then set `edx` and `ecx` to 3 and 1252, respectively, and then call `System._LStrSetLength`. In effect, I do

```
  _LStrSetLength(@result, 3, 1252)
```

where 3 is the new length of the string (in characters = bytes) and 1252 is the standard [windows-1252](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756(VS.85).aspx) codepage.

Then, knowing that `eax` is [the address of the first character of the string](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Long_String_Types), I simply set the string to "ABC". But it does not work - it gives me nonsense data or EAccessViolation. What is the problem?

## Update

Now we have two seemingly working implementations of `myfunc`, one employing `NewAnsiString` and one employing `LStrSetLength`. I cannot help but wonder if both of them are correct, in the sense  that they do not mess upp Delphi's internal handling of strings (reference counting, automatic freeing, etc.).

Comment: For Delphi/Asm questions, also Embarcadero's BASM forum is useful. Working with strings, you might also be interested in this thread: http://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=20231

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use some kind of:

```
function myfunc: AnsiString;
asm
  push eax // save @result
  call system.@LStrClr
  mov    eax,3                 {Length}
{$ifdef UNICODE}
  mov    edx,1252 // code page for Delphi 2009/2010
{$endif}
  call   system.@NewAnsiString
  pop edx
  mov [edx],eax
  mov [eax],$303132
end;
```

It will return a '210' string...

And it's always a good idea of putting a {$ifdef UNICODE} block to have your code compatible with version of Delphi prior to 2009.

Comment: This works. If I understand the code correctly, `@result` is fixed and is a pointer to the string, which is a pointer by itself, so that the first character of the string is conceptually `(@result)^^`, and not at `(@result)^`?

Comment: About the function to be called, calling NewAnsiString only will lead into some memory leaks here.

So calling LStrSetLength is the best option: it will call either NewAnsiString if the result string is '', or ReallocMem if the result string already contains characters. 

The fastest is to use LStrClr then NewAnsiString, because ReallocMem will move the previous data stored in result. See StringOfChar() function code in System.pas I've updated my example.

Answer (score 1):

With the excellent aid of A.Bouchez, I managed to correct my own code, employing `LStrSetLength`:

```
function myfunc: AnsiString;
asm

  push eax

  // eax = @result
  mov edx, 3
  mov ecx, 1252
  call System.@LStrSetLength

  pop eax

  mov ecx, [eax]

  mov [ecx], 'A'
  mov [ecx] + 1, 'B'
  mov [ecx] + 2, 'C'

end;
```